# How can i correct strobe effect

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, camera

I want to create a strobe effect,make the flashlight blink.Below is my code,right now what i have achieve is to make it flash but only once,that's why i need to help me make it flash for a great deal of time.

```
public class Strobe extends Activity {

    Camera cam;
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private Handler mHander = new Handler();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        strobe();       
    }

    private void turnOnLight(){
        for(int x = 0; x == 10; x++);{ //although for does exist does nothing and that is in all for i have put around my program,don't know why
            Log.d("tagname","runs 10 times  a");

        cam = Camera.open();
        Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(params);
        cam.startPreview();
        cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            }

        });
        }
    }

    private void turnOffLight(){
        for(int x = 0; x == 10; x++);{ 

        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
        Log.d("tagname","runs 10 times  b");

        }
    }

    private void strobe(){
        for(int x = 0; x == 10; x++);{ 
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){


                turnOnLight();
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(300);

                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                turnOffLight();
                Log.d("tagname","runs 10 times  c");


            };      
          };timer.start();
        };

    }

    };
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n=10000;
while(n-->0)
{

int n=100000;
while(n-->0) 
{
turnOnLight();
try{
      Thread.sleep(300);
   }catch(InterruptedException e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();`enter code here`
}
turnOffLight();
Log.d("tagname","runs 10 times  c");
}

}
```

Comment: Nice use of `--> (is approaching)` syntax ;)

Comment: @xinghui  Can i ask you something more as well, is there a way to make it blink without getting and releasing the camera so many times?For example do that only onStart and onStop?Because my current code limits me,i can't make it blink too fast!

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere you can override your turnOnLight() and turnOffLight() method.

Comment: @xinghui And what are they going to override?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the fact that the syntax for your for loops is all wrong? For staryers, you are using == where you probably want to use <, and you put a semicolon after the for statement where there shouldn't be one. Review the proper syntax for a for loop and try to rewrite your code.